# Toggle action for gamepad triggers, whilst being held down

Tags: game-design, input

I'm doing a small fighting game project, as up now every button command in my map code is occupied with their designated functions. All except the triggers; as up now they only have their basic "press n hold" actions assigned; "sidestep" for the [LT] and "jump/fly" for the [RT].

However there are still two more actions that I would like to implement to the triggers "if possible"; they being, "Block" for the [LT] and "Fly up" for the [RT].

That being said, is it possible to somehow, add a "tap toggle action" to the triggers while they're still being held? If yes please let me know.

---

**For Tom Tsagk:** Yes, I'm trying to cause an event while holding down a button "this case a trigger", but 'not' by pressing another button for the execution, "since every other button is occupied doing something else".

What I'm trying to attempt is: when holding a trigger down, to be able to give small "taps" to the trigger without the need let go.

Comment: I find it slightly difficult to understand the question, could you provide some more details? Are you trying to cause an event to happen when you are holding a button down and then press another button?

Comment: I think the question is whether it is possible to press and hold a given trigger then let go and press it and hold it again and have that register as a distinct action. If so, then assuming you have access to the raw inputs the answer is yes but you’ll have to keep track of the recent states of the trigger yourself and fiddle with the allowed timespans between presses. And there’s no guarantee that you will be able to get it to fell as responsive as you would like.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider doing the opposite of what you're suggesting: using your triggers to enter [quasimode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(computer_interface)#Quasimodes) and your buttons to produce actions.

If you did that, it would considerably expand your available action vocabulary. You could have a Defense mode (LT) which would transform your actions, for instance Attack would become Block and Jump would become Dodge. Similarly, RT could enter the Flying mode and transform your actions into aerial versions.

Note that you would gain a new quasimode for free! Maintaining LT + RT would give access to aerial defense moves. If you feel you want to expand your design, of course, otherwise, the last quasimode selected would cancel the previous one.

Using this approach, you could add a lot of depth and skill to a combat system, maybe having combos that require quick quasimode switching, while keeping the responsiveness of face buttons that are less "squishy" than triggers.